# Creating unity3d multiplayer(PUN/unet) browser build

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-web-player, unity-networking, unity-webgl

I have spent a lot of time with attempts to build unity3d project for browser(web player / web gl).

Web player crashes with "content was stopped because a fatal content error has been detected".
http://185.46.9.211/web_player/web_player.html

Web GL not working with strange js exceptions.
http://185.46.9.211/web_gl/index.html

Unity 5.3.1. Unet or PUN(latest from asset store) for networking. Windows 7 x64.

Windows build(exe) works fine in multiplayer mode.

Could you please explain the reason of problem in webgl or web player? Could you recommend some working tutorial?

Comment: If you're a beginner or hobbyist programmer, why not just use Unity's own networking?  I've never understood why anyone bothers with PUN unless there is some specific, highly advanced, reason.

Comment: Unet (Unity NETworking) is Unity's own networking. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. Bug was in unity 5.3.1. Version 5.3.2 works fine